# Java - int Counter isn't adding on

Tags: java

I'm wondering why my policyNumber won't increase by 1 every time the method is called.
when I run it, I get this.

I'm trying to get each Policy I add to automatically become PolicyNumber++.
Instead I'm getting the same number. Instead the same value gets assigned to all the new Policies I make.

```
run:
Policy #3 with amount $320.0
Policy #3 with amount $500.14
Policy #3 with amount $0.0
false
```

I've used this method before, I don't understand why it's not working now. Can someone shed some light please. Thank you!

main class

```
public class Assignment3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        Policy p1 = new Policy(320); 
        Policy p2 = new Policy(500.14);
        Policy p3 = new Policy(0);
        System.out.println(p2.policyNumber);
        p1.print(); System.out.println();
        p2.print(); System.out.println(); 
        p3.print(); System.out.println();
        System.out.println(p1.isExpired()); 
    }
}
```

Policy Class

```
public class Policy {
    double amount;
    public int policyCount;
    public static int policyNumber;

    public Policy(){
        amount = 0;
        policyCount = 1;
        policyNumber=0;
    }

    public Policy(double a){
        amount = a;
        policyNumber ++;
     }

    public boolean isExpired(){
        return false;
    }

    public void print(){
        System.out.print("Policy #" + this.policyNumber + " with amount $" + this.amount);
        }

}
```

Comment: If you want the value of policyNumber to be the same across all instances, you need to declare it static

Comment: Change `policyNumber` to `static`

Comment: Hi, I changed it to static and it still did not work. I'm trying to get it to out put, "Policy 1..." "Policy 2..." "Policy 3..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `policyNumber` is not static. Therefore, it is an instance variable and has its own value for every object you instantiate. If you want to make it a class variable, you should declared it static:

```
public static int policyNumber;
```

Check [this official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) about the difference between class and instance variables.

Additionally, you have to assign the static counter to an instance variable. If you just use the static variable, all your instances will have the value of the class variable. If you want to assign a value to each instance, you have to copy the value of the class variable to an instance variable.

```
public class Policy {
   double amount;
   public int policyCount;
   public static int policyNumber = 0;

   private int myPolicyNumber;

   public Policy(double a){
    amount = a;
    myPolicyNumber = policyNumber;
    policyNumber ++;

   //or even better
   //myPolicyNumber = ++policyNumber;

  }
}
```

Then you print method should look like this:

```
public void print(){
    System.out.print("Policy #" + myPolicyNumber + " with amount $" + this.amount);
}
```

Be also aware that instance variables should normally be private to obey the information hiding principle.

Comment: Hi, I changed it to static and it still did not work. I'm trying to get it to out put, "Policy 1..." "Policy 2..." "Policy 3..."

Comment: @user1692517 I edited my answer to also include that. If you just use the static variable, all your instances will have this value. If you want to assign a value to each instance, you have to copy the value of the class variable to an instance variable.

Comment: Actually, a better way is probably `myPolicyNumber = ++policyNumber;` with `static int policyNumber = 0;` (initialized for clarity). That way, you minimize the risk of multiple `Policy` objects getting the same policy number because the constructors are executed in an interleaved fashion or even in parallell. Not terribly likely with the posted example, but certainly possible in a general case, *especially* with today's multi-core CPUs. (One *could* use a `synchronized` block around the assignment and increment, but I prefer to avoid `synchronized` whenever at all possible.)

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Yes, that would be the better solution, but I opted for the solution in my answer, since I thought it is more suitable for a beginner.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, I also took Michael's advice and made it =policyNumber++;

Comment: @user1692517 `++x` and `x++` are *not the same thing* when used together with assignment. It's called pre- and postfix increment, respectively. `x = y++` will read the value of `y`, assign it to `x`, then increment `y`. `x = ++y` will increment `y`, then take the resulting value and assign it to `x`. It's a minor detail most of the time, but sometimes, it means the difference between subtle, nearly-impossible-to-track-down bugs, and properly working code.

Comment: That's not to say you should start using prefix increment everywhere. They both have their uses, and for a plain `x++;` it doesn't matter which one you use. (Except for style.) But whenever you actually *use* the value of the incremented variable *in the same statement*, it makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

change it to

```
public static int policyNumber;
```

The static keyword makes java presever the value of the variable while making a new object.

Check this out :

http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=285

Answer (score 0):

Have the policyNumber as a static variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
public static int policyNumber;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is getting incremented every time.

You have to understand that when you call the constructor thrice effectively you are creating three different objects of class policy each having its own policy number.

If you wish to have a variable common to all the objects of a class declare it static.

Answer (score 0):

In first place your policyNumber variable is a member variable and not a class variable. You need to make it static if you want to access it across class instances.

```
public int policyNumber; // Not suited for your case.
```

Instead try the following:

```
public static int policyNumber = 0;
```

Second, you are re-initializing policyNumber each time when you create instance of Policy class.

```
public Policy()
{
    policyNumber = 0; // Why to re-initialize it as you want to persist its value.
}
```

Instead try the following:

```
public Policy()
{
    policyNumber++; 
}
```